# gnuplot load does not work in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnuplot

I have a bash script to automate plotting using `gnuplot`, however the load command within `gnuplot` does not work in the bash script. The command simply gets stuck.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for k in _1 +1 _2 +2 _3 +3 _4 +4 _5 +5 _6 +6
do
    cd $k/surface

    for i in s ss
    do
        cd $i
        for j in `ls -d */`
        do
            if [ "$j" != "unrelax/" ]; then
                cd $j/spin
                echo $k$i$j

                gnuplot 
                load 't-dos.plt'
                exit            

                cd ../../
            fi
        done     
        cd ..
    done     
    cd ../../
done
```

`t-dos.plt` contains:

```
cat > t-dos.plt << eof
fermi=$(head -6 DOSCAR | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')
plot 't-dos' u (\$1-fermi):2 w l
replot 't-dos' u (\$1-fermi):3 w l
set term post enhanced color
set output 't-dos.ps'
rep
eof
```

My output is like:

entering the gnuplot and stay there forever

Comment: Your question is not well formatted. Please indent your code to fix this.

Comment: If I just type gnuplot and load the .plt file in a specific directory, it works perfectly fine. But it does not work in bash script. OMG...

Comment: Just use `gnuplot t-dos.plt` in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

When your bash script runs `gnuplot`, it's now sat waiting for gnuplot to exit before continuing any further, at which point it will then try and run a command called `load` (and probably fail). gnuplot is itself sat waiting for input giving the illusion that your script is paused or hanging.

What you're expecting to happen is for any text after the `gnuplot` line to be magically entered into the gnuplot interface, bash scripts don't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things you could do. The first was suggested in the comments:

```
gnuplot t-dos.plt
```

The other would be using a "here document":

```
gnuplot << GNUPLOT

load t-dos.plt

GNUPLOT
```